# make nightwatch to fail on warn level message

Tags: javascript, testing, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

> Warn: WaitForElement found 5 elements for selector ".modal". Only the first one will be checked.

I had this warning in my test report and fixed it with no hassle.
The problem is, I didn't even notice this warning for a while cuz nightwatch was showing this message in green text (WTF).

Is there any way to make nightwatch to fail on any kind of warning?

BTW I am using the default test runner.